# symfony 3 режет роуты

Tags: отладка, symfony3, route

После заливки приложения Symfony на хостинг в dev моде, режутся роуты. 
Например:

```
/app_dev.php/projects
```

выдает ошибку No route found for "GET jects"
тоесть режет первые три буквы роута на любом роуте 
В prod моде все нормально.
Стоит переадресация на /web/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Если зайти прямо

```
/web/app_dev.php/projects
```

то работает нормально.
В файле web/.htaccess закомментированы мультивьюс.

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
#Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

Что может быть?

Comment: Почему на хостинге вообще есть dev мод? Настройте продакшн и забудьте про dev на хосте. dev нужен только для разработки и отладки, версия на хостинге к этому не имеет никакого отношения!

Comment: согласен, но перенос на продакшн и 500-ая. Поэтому и дев. Чтобы сделать настройку единственный раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась следующим образом. 
base_url приложение получает от хостинга с /web/
а requestUri - без, так как .htaccess правило работает. 
В итоге хостеры сказали содержимое web/ перенести в корень и проблема отпала.